# How to pass event.preventDefault(); from child to parent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-events, child-to-parent

I have a wizard with a child object. The child object has an event.preventDefault(); (Step 2 wizard). How do I pass this to the wizard (parent) to prevent going to the next page (step 3) of the wizard. Currently the error is shown on the the correct page but the wizard does not receive the event.preventDefault(); and executes to the next page in the wizard.

Child

```
 next: function (component, event, helper) {

      event.preventDefault();
        let fields = component.find("field");
        let isValid = !fields.find(fld => $A.util.hasClass(fld,"poc-required") && !fld.get("v.value"));
        //alert('fields: '+$A.util.hasClass(fld,"poc-required"));
        if(isValid) {

            component.find('form').submit(); 
            document.getElementById('body').scrollIntoView(true);

            console.log("Record is created");

        } else {
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "",
                "message": "Please fill all the required fields with the red asterisks",
                type:"error"
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
        }
```

Parent component

```
<div class="{!v.currentStep == '2' ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide'}" style="color:white">
                       <!--<p>Step 2</p>-->
                   <c:FieldsetGenerator aura:id="childComp-02" genericObject="{!v.genericObject}" fieldSetName="{!v.fieldset}" recordId="{!v.recordId}"  title="" mode="{!v.mode}"/>
                    </div>
```

Parent controller

```
   moveNext : function(component,event,helper){
     // control the next button based on 'currentStep' attribute value    
        var getCurrentStep = component.get("v.currentStep");
        if(getCurrentStep == "1"){
        var childComp = component.find('childComp-01');
        childComp.callChild();            
            component.set("v.currentStep", "2");
        }
        else if(getCurrentStep == 2){
        var childComp = component.find('childComp-02');
        childComp.callChild();
            component.set("v.currentStep", "3");
        }
    },
```

Comment: where is `moveNext` of parent fired from child cmp?  i am not seen any code in your child cmp code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can achieve that by using `event.preventDefault();`. This is basically to stop default behaviour.

In your case you should have something like:

```
moveNext : function(component,event,helper){
    // control the next button based on 'currentStep' attribute value  
    if(isValid) {  
        var getCurrentStep = component.get("v.currentStep");
        if(getCurrentStep == "1"){
            var childComp = component.find('childComp-01');
            childComp.callChild();            
            component.set("v.currentStep", "2");
        }
        else if(getCurrentStep == 2){
            var childComp = component.find('childComp-02');
            childComp.callChild();
            component.set("v.currentStep", "3");
        }
    }
},
```

You should pass the `isValid` from child to parent either by 2-way binding or by component event and `moveNext` should be invoked after that when you receive `isValid`